# how to SQL the move/copy of excerpt to post body?

Tags: sql, wordpress

after a migration from Joomla to Wordpress, the texts that was to be displayed before the "rea more" have been moved to the wordpress post's excerpt.
I'd like now to move the excerpt into the top of the body the theme I'm using is not showing the excerpt.
I'm looking for an SQL command to it automatically instead of editin my 700 posts ....
any idea ?

Comment: You need to copy excerpt in post content is that you are looking for?

Comment: I know squat about joomla and wordpress, and I'm not entirely sure if I follow the question. Are you looking to take some text in field 1, and append it to the front of field 2?

Comment: YEs indeed I'd like to copy content of Excerpt into post body on top of what is already in the body. is excerpt contains "Hello" and Body contains " World" I'd like to have "Hello World" in the body after execution of the SQL